# How to detect return to the root view of the NavigationView in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I see "ContentView appeared!" message only first time/ `onAppear` seems to be called ones

Is it possible to detect return to the root in any other way?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("Hello World")
                }
            }
        }.onAppear {
            print("ContentView appeared!")
        }.onDisappear {
            print("ContentView disappeared!")
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Second View")
        }.onAppear {
                print("DetailView appeared!")
        }.onDisappear {
                print("DetailView disappeared!")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NavigationView` is persist between `view`s. So it's not actually `appear` and `disappear` when you push and pop between them. So you need to set the `modifier`s on the **NavigationView's content**, **NOT** the `NavigationView` it self:

```
NavigationView {
    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) { Text("Hello World") }

    .onAppear { print("ContentView appeared!") }
    .onDisappear { print("ContentView disappeared!") }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Found stupid solution, but it works. Just add `onAppear()` to `VStack` inside root view

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("Hello World")
                }
            }.onAppear {
            print("stack appeared!")
          }
        }.onAppear {
            print("ContentView appeared!")
        }.onDisappear {
            print("ContentView disappeared!")
        }
    }
}
```